# Compiler: how to check a user function returns properly?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, return, llvm, control-flow

I am writing a very simple compiler where users are allowed to define functions that return either `void`, `int` or `char`. However, users' function may be malformed. They may not return a value for a function that does not return `void`, or return a value for a function that returns `void` as declared. Currently my compiler is unable to detect this kind of errors and fails to generate proper code for function that returns `void` as this class of functions can return without a `return;` (they return implicitly). These two problems have cost me quite some time to phrase them out clearly. See the example code below:

```cpp
    // Problem A: detect implicit return.
    void Foo(int Arg) {
      if (Arg)
        return;
      else {
        Arg = 1;
        // Foo returns here! How can I know!
      }
    }

    // Problem B: detect "forgotten return".
    int Bar(int Arg) {
      if (Arg > 1) {
        return 1;
      }
      // this is an error: control flow reaches end at non-void function!
      // How can I know!
    }
```

I think the more general question may be: how can I tell the control flow reaches end at some point in a function? By saying *reach end* I mean the it reaches a point after which the function has no code to execute. If I can detect the end of control flow, I can look for a `return` at this point and either report an error if the function ought to return something or generate an explicit `return` for a `void` function. If I enumerate all such points of a function, I can ensure that the function is fully checked or complemented.

I see this problem as a well-solved one in compiler engineering since modern C/C++ can do that pretty well. Is `LLVM` can offer any API to do this? Or is there simple algorithm to achieve this? Thanks very much.

**Edit:** I am currently using `LLVM` and have `BasicBlock` emitted already. I hope a guide in doing this in `LLVM` specifically.

**Edit:** In this question we assume that the return type declared in the function prototype **always** matches that of its `return` stmt. I primarily focus on the **absence** of a required `return`.

Comment: Why no mention of type checking?

Comment: Sorry for missing type checking since I've somehow done it. And I want to focus on the problem related with CFG. I will make it explicit in the question that type checking is out of concern for this question.

Comment: LLVM has unifyfunctionexitnodes pass which as name suggests unifies exit nodes :) not sure if it is the same thing you are looking for, it also has getReturnBlock function which may be helpful to you. see http://llvm.org/doxygen/structllvm_1_1UnifyFunctionExitNodes.html#a5cecc9622aa7c37d2d290c729594eaf6

Comment: @ChiragPatel, thanks for your suggestion. But that's not what I am looking for. I want to make sure the user code is well-formed. Malformed user code leads to malformed IR (some BB ends without a Terminator). I am new to ``LLVM`` and not sure if any pass of it accept malformed IR. Anyway, I came out of a solution and will post it later. Keep concerned!

Answer (score 5):

The answer is simple. After all BB's of a function are emitted, loop over them and pick up those ends **without** a Terminator (see the llvm document for what is a Terminator Instruction). Assuming the emission of all kinds of control flow statements (While, For, etc.) follows the rule (One BB is ended by one and only one Terminator), the only possible explanation of these rule-breakers is that they miss a `Return` IR in the end. If the current function return `void`, append a `ReturnVoid` to them. Otherwise, this is an error, report it.

The reasoning is largely correct as it rely on the well-formed property of LLVM's BB and it is easy to implement, cheap to run. Here is the code:

```
/// Generate body for a Function.
void visitFuncDef(FuncDef *FD) {
  // Unrelated code omitted...

  /// Generate the body
  for (Stmt *S : FD->stmts) {
    visitStmt(S);
  }

  /// Check for well-formness of all BBs. In particular, look for
  /// any unterminated BB and try to add a Return to it.
  for (BasicBlock &BB : *Fn) {
    Instruction *Terminator = BB.getTerminator();
    if (Terminator != nullptr) continue; /// Well-formed
    if (Fn->getReturnType()->isVoidTy()) {
      /// Make implicit return of void Function explicit.
      Builder.SetInsertPoint(&BB);
      Builder.CreateRetVoid();
    } else {
      // How to attach source location?
      EM.Error("control flow reaches end of non-void function");
      // No source location, make errors short
      return;
    }
  }

  /// Verify the function body
  String ErrorMsg;
  llvm::raw_string_ostream OS(ErrorMsg);
  if (llvm::verifyFunction(*Fn, &OS)) {
    EM.Error(ErrorMsg);
  }
}
```